# ApplicationContextaware works

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I need to know how applicatoncontextaware works. I have applicationContext.xml which has some import resource(another applicationContext). I need to use the applicationContext.xml in my java class to use the spring beans in it.

I came to know the applicationcontextaware class which is used to get the spring beans inside java class.Applicationaware has the set and getapplicationcontext() methods. getapplicationcontext() is defined as static.

How do the applicationcontextware loads the applicationContext.xml? whether do i need to give the location of applicationContext.xml so that applicationcontextaware loads? How can i use it in my java class?

Comment: I have created ApplicationContextProvider which implements applicationcontext aware. I have defined it in the applicationContext.xml as <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.example.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>

Comment: I have personally used it in a hybrid enterprise application which was initially built on struts; but lately we have started introducing spring beans and context. Here we do not load application context using web.xml but rather we use ApplicationContextAware

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are confusing few things. First of all we are talking about [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) class, right? It has only one method:

```
setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
```

Which you usually implement like this:

```
public class MyFancyBean implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public void businessMethod() {
    //use applicationContext somehow
  }

}
```

However you rarely need to access `ApplicationContext` directly. Typically you start it once and let beans populate themselves automatically.

> I need to use the applicationContext.xml in my java class to use the spring beans in it.

Here you go:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Note that you don't have to mention files already included in `applicationContext.xml`. Now you can simply fetch one bean by name or type:

```
ctx.getBean("someName")
```

Note that there are tons of ways to start Spring - using `ContextLoaderListener`, `@Configuration` class, etc.

Comment: I have a doubt if we load the applicationcontext like this ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml"); then wats the purpose of applicationcontextaware?

Comment: @ramya: well, you tell me :-). As I said it is rarely needed, most of the time your beans are free of Spring dependencies like this.

Comment: You might need it if Spring is not in direct control of your entire application, like if you're running Spring from within an application server instance, but you want to tie instances from the two together. 

From the ApplicationContextAware javadoc, they list a number of other possibilities, but also provide you with the preferred alternatives, i.e. unless you absolutely can't use the XML / Annotations config, you shouldn't be grabbing from the context directly.