# Spring - Switch between loading test or main configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to swap application-context files so I can test in my IDE using the real one or test in my IDE using JUnit with a test one.

A bare bones example would be:

mainConfig.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myPackage" />
<bean id="myBean" class="my.class"/>
```

testConfig.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myPackage" />
<bean id="myBean" class="my.test.class"/>
```

My java code that deals with the application Context is similar to below (but is really a singleton)

```
public final class MyLoader {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    public MyLoader(){
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:/hardcoded/path/to/mainConfig.xml");
    }

    public <T> T getComponent(final Class<T> type) {
        return (T) context.getBean(type);
    }
}
```

MyLoader is called from multiple points in the code since there are many different entry points into the application.

My JUnit test code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/hardcoded/path/to/testConfig.xml")
public final class Foo{}
```

When I run a JUnit test, it will load the testConfig.xml (due to the @ContextConfiguration in the JUnit file), but it will also load the mainConfig.xml (because of the ClassPathXmlApplication). This will cause a clash since the two files are different.

What is the correct way to have all this wired where mismatches like this will not occur?

Comment: are you using maven, by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using maven

Comment: usually, no needs to create appContext every time. You can create it once on startup and store somewhere, for example in static variable. And spring has interface ApplicationContextAware, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128467/applicationcontextaware-works

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I still have a hardcoded reference in the java file to the mainConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a particular scenario given the way you are loading the spring context and accessing beans.

### A solution for your specific problem:

- **Classpath precedence**.
  Place `main.xml` and `test.xml` files in different directories but using the same name for both (e.g. `main/config.xml` and `test/config.xml`). Then configure your IDE so when running `jUnit` the test directory takes precedence over the main directory in the classpath.

  This is in fact what you get by default with `maven`. In this case you might have to cook it yourself by playing with your IDE.
- **Enviroment** variable.
  Another option, an enviroment variable to configure the location of `config.xml`, then use that value in `MyLoader`, maybe defaulting to `main.xml` to avoid extra configuration in normal execution.

  ```
  public MyLoader(){
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        System.getProperty("config.location", "classpath:path/to/mainConfig.xml"));
  ```

  Then, you can either configure your IDE to set that enviroment variable when running jUnit, or extending your tests from a base class which sets the variable accordingly:

  ```
  System.setProperty("config.location", "classpath:/path/to/testConfig.xml")
  ```

  You do not really need SpringJUnit4ClassRunner here, since by using MyLoader you are lazy-loading the context anyway.

Those are not very neat solutions.

### A better solution, at the expense of some refactoring:

**Remove `MyLoader`**, do not use a singleton to keep the spring context and/or retrieve beans.

In the entry point of your application initialize the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, then after getting the first bean/s you do not need the `ApplicationContext` anymore.

Use proper **autowiring/injection** for dependencies between components. Instead of retrieving them from `MyLoader`.

That is assuming it is a non-web application, for a web application use `ContextLoaderListener` to load the config xml.

After following this approach, you shouldn't have any problems loading a different config.xml with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` since you are not running the application from the entry point when running tests.

And you won't have `MyLoader` attempting to lazy-load the main context every time a spring component is required.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I'd probably have to go with the first choice since the refactoring doesn't make too much sense in my particular situation (multiple entry points where I only want to define the context in one place).

Answer (score -1):

you should really look into using Maven and JavaConfig.  Using XML files are 2000 style you need to update you style to make the times. Look at JavaConfig and Maven and it will be easy to do.

Comment: XML files are needed for user configuration and are therefore mandatory.  This still doesn't directly address the issue at hand.